# can we store json object/any object in postgres database without any pojo/entity class in springboot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to store some generic changable object in postgres/any database using spring boot. is this possible to store those objects without any use of pojo/entity class?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are using r2dbc in your project, there is a `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` class which you can use as a generic container for postgres's `json` and `jsonb` types (r2dbc knows how to convert from pg-json(b) to r2dbc json).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways within the SpringBoot ecosystem to do what you are describing, but the most basic would be using `JdbcTemplate`
Starting with a table that looks like this

```sql
create table foo (bar jsonb);
```

with one inserted json object:

```sql
insert into foo values ('{ "firstName": "Aurthur", "lastName": "Dent" }');
```

An method with a Spring-injected datasource would look something like this:

```
@Component
public class JsonbExample {
  @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

public void fetchJsonField() {
    var jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    List<JsonNode> nodeList = jdbcTemplate.query("select bar from foo", (RowMapper<JsonNode>) (rs, rowNum) -> {
      try {
        var obj = rs.getObject("bar", PGobject.class);
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(obj.getValue(), JsonNode.class);
      } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error(e);
        return null;
      }
    });
    System.out.println(nodeList);
  }
```

The output will be

```
[{"lastName":"Dent","firstName":"Aurthur"}]
```

Notice that the column defined as postgres type [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) gets returned as type [`PGObject`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGobject.html)